# How to access GCS bucket in springboot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

What are the configurations for GCP to read files from the GCS bucket in spring boot?

Comment: Can you add more details?
you can have GCS path as gs:// in your property file and then your code can make connection to GCS.
Sample example https://www.baeldung.com/java-google-cloud-storage

Comment: @pradeep: I want to add path in my property file.

Comment: Could you provide more details on your use case? Could you post a code snippet and add more info to your question to let us know what did you try so far, if you are facing some error etc. Providing more info will help the community give you a better answer. What do you mean property file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use Spring Cloud GCP Storage component, easy to add to your project via gradle/maven.

You can find a starter example [here](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-gcp/tree/master/spring-cloud-gcp-samples/spring-cloud-gcp-storage-resource-sample) :)

### Running the example

1. Make sure that you have the Cloud SDK configured by following [these instructions](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/).
2. Create a new bucket in Google Cloud Storage.
   You can use the `gsutil` command that comes with the Cloud SDK.

```
$ BUCKET=spring-bucket-$USER
$ gsutil makebucket gs://$BUCKET
```

3. Transfer the local `my-file.txt` file to the bucket.

```
$ gsutil copy my-file.txt gs://$BUCKET
```

4. Edit the `src/main/resources/application.properties` and set the `gcs-resource-test-bucket` property to the name of your bucket that you created in Step 2.
5. Start the `GcsApplication` Spring Boot app.

```
$ mvn spring-boot:run
```

6. Navigate to http://localhost:8080/ in your browser to print the contents of the file you uploaded in step 3.
7. To update the file contents, send a POST request to the same endpoint using `curl`:

```
$ curl -d 'new message' -H 'Content-Type: text/plain' localhost:8080
```

You should see a confirmation that the contents of the file were updated.

Answer (score 3):

You can autowire the Storage class to work with the bucket (CRUD operations).

```
@Autowired
private Storage storage;

public void store(InputStream OBJECT_TO_BE_STORED){
  Blob blob = storage.get(BUCKET_NAME).create(OBJECT_NAME, OBJECT_TO_BE_STORED);
}
```

Following properties need to be defined in the application.properties

- spring.cloud.gcp.project-id
- spring.cloud.gcp.credentials.location
- Property KV for bucket name

Maven should have the following dependencies:

```
        <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.3.RELEASE</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
   </dependencyManagement>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp-starter-storage</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

Reference:

1. https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-gcp/docs/1.2.6.RELEASE/reference/html/#spring-cloud-gcp-core
2. https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-gcp/docs/1.2.6.RELEASE/reference/html/#cloud-storage