# Refresh Spring Resource from Google Cloud Storage in Runtime

Tags: spring-boot, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, inversion-of-control

I have a file in Google Cloud Storage that is used as a resource in my Spring server. I found that there is a GCS SDK for Spring [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-gcp/docs/1.1.0.M1/reference/html/_spring_resources.html). However, it only supports fetching resources once when the application is starting, just like any Spring Resource. In my case, I need the resource to be updated periodically during runtime so no redeployment is required.

It is certainly possible to fetch the resource during runtime like mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65534683/7961069) but the memory usage might get bloated if each function call stores the resource independently. Utilizing a singleton pattern like Spring Resource would be the ideal case since the resource is planned to be used across multiple `@Service` and saving the memory usage. Is there a way to define a `@Bean` or `@Resource` and update them periodically?

Comment: Why do you say that Cloud Storage bucket fetch data at startup? The cloud storage client is loaded at startup, you only need to use this client when you need

Comment: My statement is based on the `@Value` annotation usage on the sample, which set up both the GCS client and the Spring Resource from the GCS file but only at startup If I'm correct.

Comment: Yes, `@Value` is evaluated at startup. it's better to have a function that load the file in `@PostConstruct` ( and that put the value in your Instance Variable), and call it anytime that you need to refresh the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following Guillaume's suggestion in the question's comment section, here is my implemented solution.

```java
@Component
public class FooClass implements InitializingBean {
    private static final String BUCKET_NAME = "bucket-name";
    private static final String FILE_PATH = "path/filename.extension";
    private static byte[] instanceVariable;

    @Autowired
    private Storage storage;

    public byte[] get() {
        return instanceVariable;
    }

    // Replacement of @PostConstruct
    @Override
    public void afterPropertiesSet() {
        setInstanceVariable();
    }

    @Scheduled(fixedRate = 60 * 1000) // Refresh each minute
    private void refreshAssociationRule() {
        setInstanceVariable();
    }

    private void setInstanceVariable() {
        Blob blob = storage.get(BUCKET_NAME, FILE_PATH);
        instanceVariable = blob.getContent();
    }
}
```

Another Spring Component can simply autowire the `FooClass` and get the resource.

```java
@Service
public class BarClass {
    @Autowired
    private FooClass fooClass;

    private void func() {
        byte[] resource = fooClass.get();
        // use resource here
    }
}
```

Notes: If the resource is not a "pass value of the reference" data type like String, this might cause memory bloating in parallel requests. Since each `get()` function call will allocate memory resources for the content, not only the reference.